# SQL Aggregating Pricing Data by Min and Max Record

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have the following sample data set, where I am trying to aggregate total price by year for multi year sailings.

I want to aggregate by year and include saildate and itinerary, minimum saildate/itinerarystandard for 2017 and max saildate/itinerarystandard for 2018.

[image: Current Table Structure]

So ultimately there would be two records:

[image: Sample Results I want]

Answer (score 0):

This question is not about aggregating but about picking the relevant record in each year. You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` for this (if your RDBMS, that you did not tag your question with, supports it).

The trick is to compute two row numbers in a subquery, per ascending and descending segment. Then, the outer query can decide which one should be used depending on the year:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY season ORDER BY segment) rn_asc,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY season ORDER BY segment DESC) rn_desc
    FROM mytable t
) x
WHERE
   (rn_asc = 1 AND season = 2017) 
   OR (rn_desc = 1 AND season = 2018)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by segment) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (order by segment desc) as seqnum_desc,
             sum(totalprice) over (partition by season) as season_price
      from t
     ) t
where 1 in (seqnum_asc, seqnum_desc);
```

Note:  This returns the first and last record based on the `season` without respect to the year.  For some reason, that makes more sense to me than choosing the first in one year and the last in the next year -- and it is consistent with the results you want.